# Multiple timers at once ios

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

I am making an app where the user can have multiple timers going at once and see them in a list view.

I am aware that there are 2 main options for working out time:

- Subtract the date started from current date (current date-start date)

**OR**

- Use an NSTimer and take away 1 second every second from each active timer.

I have previously been using the latter, but having looked around the internet I am starting to think that the data one may be better.

Please could you let me know which you think is best to use, and if you chose the first one (dates), please could you provide some sample code on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use an NSTimer and take away 1 second every second from each active timer. You can use this class.

```
class CustomTimer {
    typealias Update = (Int)->Void
    var timer:Timer?
    var count: Int = 0
    var update: Update?

    init(update:@escaping Update){
        self.update = update
    }
    func start(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerUpdate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func stop(){
        if let timer = timer {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
    /**
     * This method must be in the public or scope
     */
    @objc func timerUpdate() {
        count += 1;
        if let update = update {
            update(count)
        }
    }
}
```

To use multiple timer you can create multiple instance of CustomTimer, Example Code:

```
let timer1 = CustomTimer { (seconds) in
    // do whatever you want 
}
timer1.start()
let timer2 = CustomTimer { (seconds) in
    // do whatever you want
}
timer2.start()
```

**NOTE:**

timerUpdate method will be called exactly at 1 second interval. to keep some space for function execution we can set interval to 0.9 or 0.95 according to time taken by execution.

Answer (score 1):

You use both. You have one `Timer` that repeats every second. The handler for the `Timer` then iterates through your list of start dates for each of the user's timers and you update the display for each based on the current date.

Comment: Thanks! How would I do the code for the date subtraction?

Comment: `let seconds = date1.timerIntervalSince(date2)`

Comment: Thanks. And how do you get the data1 and date2 variables?

Comment: Those are your "start date" and "current date".

Comment: @D-AUK You may want to run the timer at an interval of less than one second to allow for jitter in the timer firing. It will give a smoother appearance to your updates.